# Using the gyroscope with Monotouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, gyroscope

Can anybody provide me with an example on how to use the gyroscope with Monotouch?  I can't figure out how to respond to gyro update events.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example:

```
using MonoTouch.CoreMotion;
//..

CMMotionManager motionManager;
private void StartGyro()
{
    motionManager = new CMMotionManager();
    motionManager.GyroUpdateInterval = 1/10;
    if (motionManager.GyroAvailable)
    {
        motionManager.StartGyroUpdates(NSOperationQueue.MainQueue, GyroData_Received);
    }
}

private void GyroData_Received(CMGyroData gyroData, NSError error)
{
    Console.WriteLine("rotation rate x: {0}, y: {1}, z: {2}", 
    gyroData.RotationRate.x, gyroData.RotationRate.y, gyroData.RotationRate.z);
}
```

Each of the three values of the RotationRate property of the CMGyroData instance is the amount of rotation angle per second on each axis, in radians.

Comment: Thanks for example!  I knew it was something straight forward, but couldn't put the pieces together.